# MP3 audio recording app for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone-app, mp3, audio-recording

I'm looking for a good audio recorder for iPhone/iOS that can record audio and render it as MP3 off-the-shelf.

Besides MP3 functionality, it's a big plus if it can share the files fast with few finger presses, to places like Slack, iCloud, Dropbox and Email.

<sub>*NB*: Audio recording apps that offer WAV audio could also be an alternative, although I prefer MP3 for the compression.</sub>
<sub>*NB2*: M4A won't play in Slack channels, so therefore Apple's Voice Memos and so forth are excluded.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a bit and found a quite obscure app in the appstore called [Recording & Recognize](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-transcript-void/id999449899?mt=8) which works acceptably good and can encode mp3 in-app.

Still looking for alternatives.

Just for the record, an alternative solution I have right now which is complicated and not-so-mobile, is to share m4a recordings a Dropbox folder from my iOS Device, and then my computer which is usually on will run a ffmpeg script on that monitored folder and convert the audio to mp3. It has the added benefit of being able to run various other functions, like renaming, sorting and increasing the speed of speech. I can then get the new file on my iOS Device from the Dropbox app.